# Convert * pointer to *** pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have a flat, dynamically allocated 1d array (let's call it `vector`) that will contain some 3d data. Is there any way to create another pointer (let's call it `tensor`) that would "see" `vector` as 3d array, so I can access it as `tensor[i][j][k]`?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
int x, y, z; //Number of rows, cols, ...
double *vector;
double ***tensor;

x = 10; y = 10; z = 10;
vector = (double *) malloc(x * y * z * sizeof(double));

tensor = (double ***) vector;
tensor[0] = (double **) vector;
tensor[0][0] = (double *) vector;

for(j = 1; j < y; j++) {
    tensor[0][j] = tensor[0][j-1] + z;
}
for(i = 1; i < x; i++) {
    tensor[i] = tensor[i - 1] + y;
    tensor[i][0] = tensor[i - 1][0] + y * z;
    for(j = 1; j < y; j ++) {
        tensor[i][j] = tensor[i][j - 1] + z;
    }
}

tensor[0][0][0] = 1.0; //Segfaults here
tensor[0][0][1] = 2.0;
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can give you example of allocating 2d array as array of pointers plus 1d array of data
In one malloc

```
const int M = 100;
const int N = 200;
int **a = NULL;
int i, j;

a = malloc(M * sizeof(int*) + N * M * sizeof(int));
a[0] = (int*)(a + M);
for (i = 1; i < M; i++) {
    a[i] = a[0] + i * N;
}

//some code

free(a);
```

An image

[image]

And in two mallocs

```
const int M = 100;
const int N = 200;
int **a = NULL;
int i;

a = malloc(M * sizeof(int*));
a[0] = malloc(M * N * sizeof(int));
for (i = 1; i < M; i++) {
    a[i] = a[0] + i * N;
}

//Some code

free(a[0]);
free(a);
```

An Image

[image]

Here are 2 benefits: 1st - quick allocation, second - a[0] is the beginning of 1d array, so you can treat it as 1d. And yes - I'm too lazy to post full solution for 3d array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using C, not C++, you may just use a real 3D array:

```
int x = 10, y = 10, z = 10;
double (*tensor)[y][z] = malloc(x * sizeof(*tensor));

tensor[0][0][0] = 1.0; //No segfaults here anymore...
tensor[0][0][1] = 2.0;
...
```

The trick is to define `tensor` as a pointer to an array of arrays of doubles, not as a multilevel pointer. The effect is pretty much the same as if you had done this:

```
int x = 10, y = 10, z = 10;
double tensor[x][y][z];

tensor[0][0][0] = 1.0; //Might segfault, because we allocated a large 3D array on the stack.
tensor[0][0][1] = 2.0;
...
```

The only difference is where the array of arrays of arrays is allocated - you shouldn't use the later version that allocates on the stack, stack space is a bit limited. The memory layout of the resulting 3D array, however, is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate memory for the pointers to pointers that are stored in `tensor`. `tensor` is a pointer to pointer-to-pointer, so it needs memory for all pointers to pointers that you are allocating.

example:

```
double*** tensor = new double**[10]; // 10 double pointers are allocated
```

Similarly for next inner dimension.

Comment: Ok, I tried with `tensor[0] = (double **) malloc(x * sizeof(double **));` and `tensor[0][0] = (double *) malloc(x * y * sizeof(double *));` and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: That is not a C answer.

Comment: @nix, didn't realize that is a `C`-only question, but it's obvious that one replaces `new` by `malloc` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an alternative approach where you don't convert the vector and instead use functions that "see" the vector as a tensor.

```
double getValueFromTensor(double * vector,
                          size_t dim_x,
                          size_t dim_y,
                          size_t dim_z,
                          int x, int y, int z);

void setValueToTensor(   double * vector,
                          size_t dim_x,
                          size_t dim_y,
                          size_t dim_z,
                          double value, int x, int y, int z);
```

Comment: I considered this approach, but the problem is that it would require simple but massive changes in my code, which until recently only used 3d arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A `double ***` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a `double`, not a 3-dimensional array of `double`.  To dereference `double foo[1][2][3]`, we do something akin to this:

```
a = *(foo + 1*sizeof(double))
b = *(a + 2*sizeof(double))
return *(b + 3*sizeof(double)
```

You seem to be assuming that it works more like this:

```
return *(foo + length(foo[0][0][0]) + length(foo[0][0][1]) + ... + length(foo[1][0][0])+ length(foo[1][0][1] + ... + 3*sizeof(double)
```

That's not how arrays in C work.  For one thing, C doesn't keep track of the lengths of all of the sub-arrays, so there's no way to make that calculation at run-time.  There's nothing stopping you from implementing your own dereferencing function that treats a 1-d array as having as many dimensions as you want, as long as you keep track of the sub-array lengths somehow, but you can't use the standard `[]` operator like this.

If you want to be able to dereference a 3-d array as `foo[0][0][0]`, you'll need to allocate it as follows (making some assumptions about the array lengths that you want and omitting error checking for clarity):

```
double*** tensor = malloc(a*sizeof(double**);
for (unsigned i=0; i<a; ++i) {
    tensor[i] = malloc(b * sizeof(double*));
    for (unsigned j=0; i<b; ++j)
        tensor[i][j] = malloc(c * sizeof(double));
}
```